# Отладка во flashbuilder mac ?

Tags: отладка, flash, mac, actionscript

Как в flashbuilder настроить отладку? А то выскакивает такое окно:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cкорее всего не стоит дебаг версия флэш плеера в браузере.

тут можно скачать нужную версию
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: @ShockWave уже один раз скачал , установил - не помогло, удалил все установил заново - не помогло

Comment: в маке не силен
может как версии для проверки:

- другие браузеры попробовать
- железно проверить версию плеера в браузере
- проверить работает ли дебаг в AIR приложениях

Comment: заработало в safari ! видимо проблемы в chrome.

Comment: рад был помочь!